# Update run-length ID but skip NA

Tags: r, dplyr

Given this type of data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:10,
  Sequ = c(NA, 44,44, NA, NA, 33,33,33, 5,5),
  Q = c(NA, "q1","q1", NA, NA, "q2","q2","q2", "q2","q2")
)
```

how can I **update the run-length ID of `Sequ` more efficiently** than by doing this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
left_join(df, df %>%
  filter(!is.na(Sequ)) %>%
  mutate(Sequ_0 = rleid(Sequ))) %>%
  select(-Sequ)
   ID    Q Sequ_0
1   1 <NA>     NA
2   2   q1      1
3   3   q1      1
4   4 <NA>     NA
5   5 <NA>     NA
6   6   q2      2
7   7   q2      2
8   8   q2      2
9   9   q2      3
10 10   q2      3
```

Note: although I'm using `rleid` from `data.table` I'm looking for a `tidyverse` solution.

Comment: Why dont you want `rleid`?

Comment: You can replace `rleid` with `consecutive_id` from `dplyr` `v1.1.0`

Answer (score 5):

```
df %>%
   mutate(Sequ_0 = dense_rank(NA^is.na(Q)*consecutive_id(Sequ)))

   ID Sequ    Q Sequ_0
1   1   NA <NA>     NA
2   2   44   q1      1
3   3   44   q1      1
4   4   NA <NA>     NA
5   5   NA <NA>     NA
6   6   33   q2      2
7   7   33   q2      2
8   8   33   q2      2
9   9    5   q2      3
10 10    5   q2      3

df %>%
   mutate(Sequ_0 = dense_rank(`is.na<-`(consecutive_id(Sequ), is.na(Q))))
```

Also:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Sequ_0 =  replace(Q, !is.na(Q), consecutive_id(na.omit(Sequ))))
```

Comment: Very neat trick with NA^TRUE = NA and NA^FALSE = 1

Comment: Very cool! Could you elaborate on the syntax here? I'm not familiar with `^` used in this way...

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann it is same as 42^1=42 vs 42^0=1. Yes, some description would be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Using *consecutive_id* to get ids, then exclude NAs, convert to factor, then back to numeric to have sequential numbers:

```
library(dplyr) # dplyr_1.1.0 - consecutive_id

df %>% 
  mutate(id = as.numeric(as.factor(
    if_else(is.na(Sequ), NA, consecutive_id(Sequ)))))
#    ID Sequ    Q id
# 1   1   NA <NA> NA
# 2   2   44   q1  1
# 3   3   44   q1  1
# 4   4   NA <NA> NA
# 5   5   NA <NA> NA
# 6   6   33   q2  2
# 7   7   33   q2  2
# 8   8   33   q2  2
# 9   9    5   q2  3
# 10 10    5   q2  3
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option using `arrange` with `consecutive_id`:

```
library(dplyr) #dplyr >= 1.1.0
df %>% 
  arrange(Q) %>% 
  mutate(Sequ_0 =  consecutive_id(Sequ),
         Sequ_0 = ifelse(is.na(Sequ), NA_real_, Sequ_0)) %>% 
  arrange(ID)

   ID Sequ    Q Sequ_0
1   1   NA <NA>     NA
2   2   44   q1      1
3   3   44   q1      1
4   4   NA <NA>     NA
5   5   NA <NA>     NA
6   6   33   q2      2
7   7   33   q2      2
8   8   33   q2      2
9   9    5   q2      3
10 10    5   q2      3
```

Answer (score 1):

An option could be using `match` with `unique` to create the ID like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  left_join(., df %>%
              drop_na() %>%
              mutate(Sequ_0 = match(Sequ, unique(Sequ))))
#> Joining with `by = join_by(ID, Sequ, Q)`
#>    ID Sequ    Q Sequ_0
#> 1   1   NA <NA>     NA
#> 2   2   44   q1      1
#> 3   3   44   q1      1
#> 4   4   NA <NA>     NA
#> 5   5   NA <NA>     NA
#> 6   6   33   q2      2
#> 7   7   33   q2      2
#> 8   8   33   q2      2
#> 9   9    5   q2      3
#> 10 10    5   q2      3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Though I like this solution it fails when `Sequ` values are the same across distinct `Sequ` groups (and it's just slightly more efficient/concise than my solution)

Comment: I do not think match solves the problem. Suppose you had another 2 rows with `ID=11,12, Sequ = 44,44, Q = q1,q2`, then this will give you `1,1` instead of `4,4`

Answer (score 1):

in base R:

```
transform(df, seq0 = with(rle(Sequ), 
          rep(`[<-`(values, !is.na(values), seq(na.omit(values))), lengths)))

   ID Sequ    Q seq0
1   1   NA <NA>   NA
2   2   44   q1    1
3   3   44   q1    1
4   4   NA <NA>   NA
5   5   NA <NA>   NA
6   6   33   q2    2
7   7   33   q2    2
8   8   33   q2    2
9   9    5   q2    3
10 10    5   q2    3
```

---

Back to basics:

```
a <- rle(df$Sequ)
a$values[!is.na(a$values)] <- seq_along(na.omit(a$values))
cbind(df, sequ_0 = inverse.rle(a))

   ID Sequ    Q sequ_0
1   1   NA <NA>     NA
2   2   44   q1      1
3   3   44   q1      1
4   4   NA <NA>     NA
5   5   NA <NA>     NA
6   6   33   q2      2
7   7   33   q2      2
8   8   33   q2      2
9   9    5   q2      3
10 10    5   q2      3
```