# More efficient solution to create run-length id for consecutuve non-NA values

Tags: r, dplyr

This question is related to [Update run-length ID but skip NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75681910/update-run-length-id-but-skip-na).

In this type of data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:10,
  Q_segment = c(NA, "tcu_pol","frg", NA, NA, "tcu_wh","tcu_wh", NA, "xy","m,n")
)
```

I need to create a **run-length id** for consecutive non-NA values in `Q_segment`. I do have a `dplyr` solution for this but it looks way to complicated:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Q_sequence = +!is.na(Q_segment),
         Q_sequence = if_else(Q_sequence == 0, NA, consecutive_id(Q_sequence)),
         Q_sequence = dense_rank(NA^is.na(Q_sequence)*consecutive_id(Q_sequence))
         )
   ID Q_segment Q_sequence
1   1      <NA>         NA
2   2   tcu_pol          1
3   3       frg          1
4   4      <NA>         NA
5   5      <NA>         NA
6   6    tcu_wh          2
7   7    tcu_wh          2
8   8      <NA>         NA
9   9        xy          3
10 10       m,n          3
```

Is there a more efficient solution using `tidyverse`?

Comment: The third expression in your attempt will work without needing the preceding ones if you use `dense_rank(NA^is.na(Q_segment)*consecutive_id(is.na(Q_segment))`.

Comment: That's brilliant. Please post as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```r
df %>%
  mutate(Q_sequence = as.numeric(factor(consecutive_id(is.na(Q_segment)) * 
                                          (Q_segment != 1))))
#>    ID Q_segment Q_sequence
#> 1   1      <NA>         NA
#> 2   2   tcu_pol          1
#> 3   3       frg          1
#> 4   4      <NA>         NA
#> 5   5      <NA>         NA
#> 6   6    tcu_wh          2
#> 7   7    tcu_wh          2
#> 8   8      <NA>         NA
#> 9   9        xy          3
#> 10 10       m,n          3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
df %>%
    mutate(
        Q_sequence = with(
            rle(!is.na(Q_segment)),
            replace(rep(cumsum(values), lengths), is.na(Q_segment), NA)
        )
    )
```

which gives

```
   ID Q_segment Q_sequence
1   1      <NA>         NA
2   2   tcu_pol          1
3   3       frg          1
4   4      <NA>         NA
5   5      <NA>         NA
6   6    tcu_wh          2
7   7    tcu_wh          2
8   8      <NA>         NA
9   9        xy          3
10 10       m,n          3
```